# Positioning on top of picture css html

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a game for fun can you guys help me to position health and mana bars on top of characters correctly ?  I showed correct positions with arrows.also my css code might be unnecessary dublicated.
Right now it looks like that:

[image: image of duel]

```
<div class="progress-container player-health">
    <progress id="playerhealth" *ngIf="state==1"  id="playerhealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
      {{hp}}
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="progress-containermana">
    <progress id="playermana" *ngIf="state==1"   value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
      {{playermana}}player
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="progress-container enemy-health">
    <progress id="enemyhealth" *ngIf="state==1"   id="ophealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
  {{ophp}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="progress-containermana">
    <progress id="opmana" *ngIf="state==1"   value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
      {{opmana}}op
    </p>

  </div>
<div>
  <img *ngIf="state==1" width="200" height="100" class="avatarimg" src="{{playeravatar}}">
  <img *ngIf="state==1" width="200" height="100" class="op" src="{{opavatar}}">
</div>
```

css:

```
.avatarimg{
      width: auto;
      margin-left: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
  }

  .progress-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  }
  .progress-container progress {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  }

  .progress-container progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
  }

  .progress-container progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
  }

  .progress-container .progress-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  left: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Minecraft;
  }
  .op{
      width: auto;
      margin-left: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-animation: bounce ease-in 5;
animation: bounce ease-in 5;
-webkit-animation-duration: 20000ms;
animation-duration: 1000ms;
  }

  .progress-containermana {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  }
  .progress-containermana progress {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 20px;
  }

  .progress-containermana progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #eee;
  }

  .progress-containermana progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: blue;
  }
  .progress-containermana .progress-label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      margin: 0;
      left: 60px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Minecraft;
  }
```

Comment: can you reduce your code to a [mcve]? right now it seems like a lot of code which we need to spend more time parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple fix of your problem could include:
moving the divs arround to have another order of elements like this:

```
  <div class="progress-container player-health">
    <progress id="playerhealth" *ngIf="state==1"  id="playerhealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
      {{hp}}
    </p>

  </div>

  <div class="progress-container enemy-health">
    <progress id="enemyhealth" *ngIf="state==1"   id="ophealth" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
  {{ophp}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="progress-containermana">
        <progress id="playermana" *ngIf="state==1"   value="100" max="100"></progress>
        <p class="progress-label">
          {{playermana}}player
        </p>
      </div>
  <div class="progress-containermana">
    <progress id="opmana" *ngIf="state==1"   value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <p class="progress-label">
      {{opmana}}op
    </p>

  </div>
```

I just changed the order of 2nd and 3rd "element" (to have both red ones first, then the blue in your image). Then you can add a simple line break `<br>` element to force the first blue element to go to new line.

Answer (score 1):

## There are many solutions, but try [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.progress-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Ultimately, you're trying to control the alignment and positioning of the box model with css.  The old method of doing this is to define each column as a block-element, then `float:left; width: 50%;` these columns. The new *flexbox* approach, is to defined the "text-direction" however you need the content to flow, in this case: first a column top-to-bottom, and wrap to the next column.

#### Old float approach

```css
.container {
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 2%;
}

.container div {
   margin: 5px;
   background-color: #7f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Something1</div>
    <div>Something2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>Something3</div>
    <div>Something4</div>
</div>
```

#### Flexbox Columns

Try playing with changing the `flex-flow` and `height` properties, to see what happens.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 4.4em;
}

.container div {
   margin: 0.1em;
   background-color: #7f7;
   height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Something1</div>
    <div>Something2</div>
    <div>Something3</div>
    <div>Something4</div>
</div>
```